# Rolling sum does not show zero when sum of windows value is zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using a rolling sum to calculate the sum of the previous 48 values. However, I noticed that in the output when there is all zero value in the windows of 48 values, instead of showing rolling sum 0, it shows some number. I have attached the snapshot of the output file. Here is my code for calculating rolling sum:

```
temp_final=temp_final.rolling(48).sum()
```

[image]

I took the snapshot of the output from middle of the output, that's why its not showing Nan in first 47 values. Could anyone help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises with [how the floating point calculations are performed](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html).  You may consider values less than, say, 1e-9 as effectively 0, yielding the following filter for your data:

```py
temp_final=temp_final.rolling(48).sum().apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 1e-9 else x)
```